# document.querySelectorAll select id of specific input

Tags: javascript, salesforce, selectors-api

I have a table which has two separate checkbox inputs. When selecting the first input there is a cumulative amount which calculates. If you select the second checkbox, the function errors (because of the duplicate input).

**Function**

```
function updateTotals() {
    var sum = Array.prototype.reduce.call(document.querySelectorAll("input.check:checked"),(a,v) => a + parseFloat(v.dataset.totalAmount), 0);
    $('#checkedTotal').val(sum);
};
```

What I need to do is separate the inputs, maybe using a class. I cant seem to get the syntax, or may be barking up the wrong tree. Something like...

```
function updateTotals() {
    var sum = Array.prototype.reduce.call(document.querySelectorAll ('.input').check:checked,(a,v) => a + parseFloat(v.dataset.totalAmount), 0);
    $('#checkedTotal').val(sum);
};
```

I would add this as an jsfiddle example, but the table is in a Salesforce Visualforce Page, using apex fields.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

Added HTML

```
<div style="width:50%;">
<form id="j_id0:j_id2" name="j_id0:j_id2" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="j_id0:j_id2" value="j_id0:j_id2">


    <input disabled="disabled" id="checkedTotal" name="amount" placeholder="Selected Amount" step=".02" type="number">

    <table id="invoicesTable" style="width:100%;">
        <thead class="tableHeadBlue">
            <tr>
                <td>Select</td>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td>Type</td>
                <td>Order</td>
                <td>Amount</td>
                <td>id</td>
                <td>Select2</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label class="formCheck"><input id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:0:inputId" type="checkbox" name="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:0:inputId" class="check" onchange="updateTotals();" style="font-size:26px;" data-total-amount="458.00">
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:0:j_id7">19/04/2018</span>
                        <span style="color:red;">
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>Invoice
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span style="color:Black"><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:0:j_id14">00006648</span>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:0:j_id16">$458.00</span></td>
                    <td><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:0:j_id18">8015D000000CsiH</span></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:0:j_id20" class="check" style="font-size:26px;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label class="formCheck"><input id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:1:inputId" type="checkbox" name="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:1:inputId" class="check" onchange="updateTotals();" style="font-size:26px;" data-total-amount="200.00">
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:1:j_id7">21/06/2018</span>
                        <span style="color:red;">
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>Invoice
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span style="color:Black"><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:1:j_id14">00006849</span>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:1:j_id16">$200.00</span></td>
                    <td><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:1:j_id18">8015D000000DEuB</span></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:1:j_id20" class="check" style="font-size:26px;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label class="formCheck"><input id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:2:inputId" type="checkbox" name="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:2:inputId" class="check" onchange="updateTotals();" style="font-size:26px;" data-total-amount="500.00">
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span style="color:red;"><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:2:j_id9">22/06/2018</span>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td><span style="color:red;">Credit</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span style="color:red"><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:2:j_id14">00006852</span>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:2:j_id16">$500.00</span></td>
                    <td><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:2:j_id18">8015D000000DHKW</span></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:2:j_id20" class="check" style="font-size:26px;"></td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table><div id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id24"></div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you at least post the HTML?

Comment: Thanks CP, have updated

Comment: What's the purpose of the 2nd column of checkboxes? Is it supposed to calculate values differently? It looks like it does the exact same calculation as the 1st column of checkboxes.

Comment: @zer00ne because this is a wrapper class in Salesforce, the return value of the second checkbox is sent to the Apex Class, to action on save against the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add class `first` to first checkbox in `<tr>` and add class `second` to second checkbox in `<tr>`.

`updateTotals` only query checkbox which has class `first` to avoid `second`.

```js
function updateTotals() {
    var sum = Array.prototype.reduce.call(document.querySelectorAll("input.check.first:checked"),(a,v) => a + parseFloat(v.dataset.totalAmount), 0);
    $('#checkedTotal').val(sum);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:50%;">
<form id="j_id0:j_id2" name="j_id0:j_id2" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="j_id0:j_id2" value="j_id0:j_id2">


    <input disabled="disabled" id="checkedTotal" name="amount" placeholder="Selected Amount" step=".02" type="number">

    <table id="invoicesTable" style="width:100%;">
        <thead class="tableHeadBlue">
            <tr>
                <td>Select</td>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td>Type</td>
                <td>Order</td>
                <td>Amount</td>
                <td>id</td>
                <td>Select2</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label class="formCheck"><input id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:0:inputId" type="checkbox" name="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:0:inputId" class="check first" onchange="updateTotals();" style="font-size:26px;" data-total-amount="458.00">
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:0:j_id7">19/04/2018</span>
                        <span style="color:red;">
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>Invoice
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span style="color:Black"><span  id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:0:j_id14">00006648</span>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:0:j_id16">$458.00</span></td>
                    <td><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:0:j_id18">8015D000000CsiH</span></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:0:j_id20" class="check second" style="font-size:26px;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label class="formCheck"><input id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:1:inputId" type="checkbox" name="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:1:inputId" class="check first" onchange="updateTotals();" style="font-size:26px;" data-total-amount="200.00">
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:1:j_id7">21/06/2018</span>
                        <span style="color:red;">
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>Invoice
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span style="color:Black"><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:1:j_id14">00006849</span>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:1:j_id16">$200.00</span></td>
                    <td><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:1:j_id18">8015D000000DEuB</span></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:1:j_id20" class="check second" style="font-size:26px;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label class="formCheck"><input id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:2:inputId" type="checkbox" name="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:2:inputId" class="check first" onchange="updateTotals();" style="font-size:26px;" data-total-amount="500.00">
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span style="color:red;"><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:2:j_id9">22/06/2018</span>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td><span style="color:red;">Credit</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span style="color:red"><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:2:j_id14">00006852</span>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:2:j_id16">$500.00</span></td>
                    <td><span id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:2:j_id18">8015D000000DHKW</span></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="j_id0:j_id2:j_id4:2:j_id20" class="check second" style="font-size:26px;"></td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table><div id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id24"></div>
</form>
</div>
```